# Send from shared mailbox via AX2012

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have created a class to send out e-mails fromout AX2012 via Outlook. Herefore I am using the class: `SmmOutlookEmail`.

Sending the e-mails is working fine, there is only 1 thing I want to change, I want to use a different "From address" (shared mailbox) then my default From address in outlook.

I have investigated the class, but I can't find the right syntax to control the From field.

How can I control the From field in Outlook from out the class?

Comment: Did you try to modify the `Sender` property of the `MailItem`? You should be able to modify it like the other properties (e.g. `To`) get modified in method `sendEMail` of the class (see also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869056.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, i am going to try this, the link is very helpfull.